# Register HttpContext.User with Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I would like to do the following in Autofac, but not sure how?

This is how you do it in StructureMap

```
ForRequestedType<IPrincipal>()
  .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid)
  .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(ctx => HttpContext.Current.User);
```

Answer (score 13):

For ASP.NET MVC 1 and 2:

```
builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User).HttpRequestScoped();
```

For ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User).InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

For Autofac ASP.NET MVC3 integration you may take a [look at the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration3) (updated link).

For ASP.NET MVC 5:

```
builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: what additional information is in the documentation that isn't in this post?

Comment: Which changed to `InstancePerRequest()` in MVC 5 (maybe 4).