# How to resolve connection string parameter at runtime in autofac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I am using autofact in my project to implement dependency injection. I have a situation where one master and other client databases. When user login we get connection string from database and want to resolve connection string parameter using ContainerBuilder of autofact. I am using following code which successfully register parameter with constant value.

```
builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>()
       .As<IDbFactory>()
       .WithParameter("connectionString", "...")
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

But this code will only work if the value is known at registration time. But I needs a value known only at at runtime. I have tried something like this at controller level as given below, but no help.

```
 UserViewModel userModel = new UserViewModel();
 userModel.Code = _userContext.User.Code;
 userModel.Username = _userContext.User.Username;
 userModel.Email = _userContext.User.Email;
 userModel.IsLocked = _userContext.User.IsLocked;
 userModel.ConnectionString = _userContext.User.ConnectionString;


 CurrentLoginUser = userModel;

 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

 builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>()
        .As<IDbFactory>()
        .WithParameter("connectionString", userModel.ConnectionString)
        .InstancePerRequest();

 Autofac.IContainer container = builder.Build();
 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: See [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). Your connection string is a _runtime value_ and you should _not_ use it during object construction, but instead pass it along method calls on an already initialized object graph.

Answer (score 0):

The `WithParameter` method can have lambda expression parameter :

```
builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>()
       .WithParameter((pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string) 
                            && pi.Name == "connectionString",
                      (pi, ctx) => "runtime executed"));
```

The second lambda will be executed at runtime. `ctx` is the ambiant context, you can resolve other things here too.

If you want to access user information :

```
builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>()
       .WithParameter((pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string) 
                            && pi.Name == "connectionString",
                      (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<UserContext>().User.ConnectionString));
```

Comment: As my connection string will be user based so how will I pass my connection string parameter to it from controller ?

Comment: You should Register the user and then resolve it using the `ctx` parameter. See the edit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203139/register-httpcontext-user-with-autofac for more information